# from solidity: TypeError: Contract "ConcreteNFTmarketplace" should be marked as abstract

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts

I have this smart contract.. But it gives me this error .. I know there are a lot of questions out there about this matter but did not find an answer there including two contracts

> from solidity: TypeError: Contract "ConcreteNFTmarketplace" should be marked as abstract.

Even though NFTmarketplace is marked as abstract why is that

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";

abstract contract NFTmarketplace is ERC721URIStorage, IERC721Receiver {

    constructor() ERC721("astro market", "astro"){
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
}

contract ConcreteNFTmarketplace is NFTmarketplace {

    function onERC721Received(address _from, uint256 _tokenId) external  {
        // Transfer the received ERC721 token to the owner
        transferFrom(_from, address(this), _tokenId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edit your code, all working good. About inhereting IERC721Receiver, there is actually no need, because to receive nfts you can just implement function onERC721Received like i did in ConcreteNFTmarketplace, but you can also inherit nothing wrong with it.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract NFTmarketplace is ERC721URIStorage {
address public owner; 

constructor() ERC721("astro market", "astro"){
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
}

function mint(address to, uint tokenId) public {
    _mint(to, tokenId);
}
}

contract ConcreteNFTmarketplace is NFTmarketplace {

// function onERC721Received(address _from, uint256 _tokenId) external  {
//     // Transfer the received ERC721 token to the owner
//     transferFrom(_from, address(this), _tokenId);
// }

function onERC721Received(address, address, uint256, bytes memory) public virtual returns (bytes4) {
    return this.onERC721Received.selector;
} 
}
```

Comment: That sounds good i will test it out, and mark your answer as correct if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to inherit from IERC721Receiver.

```
contract NFTmarketplace is ERC721URIStorage {your contract}
```

Comment: Yes I do if i want the contract to be able to receive NFT on the safetransfer